# String encoding in class library project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing a strange problem.

I have a solution that contains an Android project and a class library project.

If in that library project I execute this line:

```
String s = "Código inválido";
```

This is actually shown when watching the variable: `CÃ³digo invÃ¡lido`.

However, when I do that assignment inside the Activity code, the text is shown correctly as `Código inválido`.

What may be wrong with this?

The origin of the problem was when I tried to show, in the Activity layout, a text that was assigned in a class library method. After a lot of digging, I found what I expose in this question.

Just in case, I tell you that all files encodings are UTF-8, and in the project settings all encodings are also UTF-8.

This is Android Studio 4.0.1

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: it might sound weird... but I do speak Spanish, and I am assuming that you also do. Can it be a set up on the user's device? because I've seen this with special characters only

Comment: Hello, but why the diference between  assigning that string in a class library and in the main project code? If some strange setting is wrong, that should affect both the class library and the activity code.

Comment: I faced this problem before but unfortunately wouldn't remember how I solved it. Why do you not putting these kinds of Unicode strings in XML string resources? Surely it solves the issue. Is it necessary to have these strings hardcode in java files?

Comment: @aminography This is a class library project to be shared with the Android project and with the iOS project, so I cannot depend on certain platform with respect to resources. Finally, I have used this: `String s = "C\u00f3digo inv\u00e1lido"` and I solved the problem. Very ugly, don't you think so?

Comment: Well , replacing special characters with their Unicode is a good solution until a better one would come.

Comment: How about sharing project source code on Github without any important codes.